# Optimize Integral Equation using Scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to minimize a function (w.r.t parameters 'a' and 'b' below), which is defined in terms of an integral. To this end I use Scipy’s minimize. Likewise, the integrand also takes a function as input. My cost function looks like this:

```
def cost_func(a,b,func):
    return dblquad(integrand,0,C,lambda x1:0,lambda x2:C,args=(func,a,b))[0]
```

C is some global variable.

The integrand is here defined by

```
def integrand(x1,x2,func,a,b):
    return func(x1,x2,a,b)
```

The functions 'integrand' and 'cost_func' are sane (insofar as they give numbers as output). Now for the minimisation part:

```
x0 = [5,5]
result = minimize(cost_func,x0,args=(a,b,func),method=('Nelder-Mead'))
```

Note: 'func' in minimize can be any number of given set of functions, e.g.,

```
def func1(x1,x2,a,b):
    return some real number
```

When I call minimize (for some func), I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./update.py", line 54, in <module>
minimize(cost_func,x0,args=(a,b,func),method=('Nelder-Mead'))
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I am guessing I'm not using the variables in a correct way, and that's what causing my problem. Am I right in assuming that this why the minimization fails? Are there any good rules of thumb in situations like this when you have a bit more complicated structure of arguments that go in to several functions?

Many thanks.

Comment: The minimization is not failing, because Python has not yet had a chance to call `minimize`.  The error occurs when Python tries to evaluate the arguments to `minimize`.  You gave the argument `args=(a,b,func)`, but apparently you haven't defined the value of `a` before doing that.  Note: it would be easier for someone to help you further if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `NameError` is raised because you haven't defined `a` in your code. Also, what are your trying to find? `a` and `b`? In that case, you cannot pass them as arguments in `minimize`